# Git Peer to Peer sharing - fatal: read error: Invalid argument

Tags: git

In Git, i tried peer to peer sharing in my local network, but ended with the error  "fatal: read error: Invalid argument".

I followed below steps.

PC1:

```
$cd /d/all-repos
$git daemon --verbose --export-all –base-path=.
```

PC2:

```
$cd <repository name>
$git remote add developer1 git://<PC1 name or IP address>/testrepo
$git fetch developer1
fatal: read error: Invalid argument
```

Git version : git version 1.7.11.msysgit.0
OS: Win XP
Note: 
Added the git port 9418 in firewall settings on both the PC's.

Pls Guide me how to solve this.

Comment: Does your `testrepo` have at least one commit?

Comment: Yes Vonc, it has two or more commits

Comment: I'd be wary of using `.` in your base-path (which only has one - BTW).  Does using `--base-path=/d/all-repos` change anything?  Also, what goes `git fetch -v` show?

Comment: You can use `GIT_TRACE=2 git <command>` to see a bit more of what is going on.

Comment: I realize this is probably just a typo in your post, but you did put 2 dashes before base-path, right?

Answer (score 1):

When doing the following steps, everything works:

```
~/git1$ git init foo
# create some commits in foo
~/git1$ git daemon --verbose --export-all --port=9999 --base-path=$PWD

~/git1$ cd ../git2
~/git2$ git clone git://[::1]:9999/foo
# cloning works
```

Which means that either something is bad with either of your repositories or that it is not a git issue but a network issue. In any case, you should try solving your problem with a more interactive process than stackoverflow, maybe some IRC #git channel.